# Is this fairing covered in thick thermal insulation? Keeping the payload warm? Or Cold?

Tags: russia, fairings, soyuz-launcher

I was enjoying some 2017 April 13 tweets on robots and reminiscing about shoveling snow after seeing [this one](https://twitter.com/Rogozin/status/853282603453075458), but then I scrolled down further and saw a video of a rocket. It's also [here in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjaWfn8TwRg&feature=youtu.be&t=89), where the information seems to say it is the first launch from [Vostochny Cosmodrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostochny_Cosmodrome).

**edit:** The time line is not 100% clear - there is dry snow on the ground in the screen shots shown below, but by the time the actual launch happens, there is no snow, nor wet ground where it would have melted recently. The screen shots at the bottom clearly show different weather and different fairing covers - it looks like these are two different days. However, my question is simply about the need for insulation.

Perhaps the screenshots below really represent a "dry run" — testing and preparation for [this launch](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/soyuz2-vostochny-first-launch.html)?

It is certainly a "cool" video (manage your volume, there is a sound track) but is the Amur Oblast really colder than (a spacecraft might become when it is in) space? Or have I got it wrong, and the payload is pre-cooled cryogenic and the local ambient is actually too hot?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Weather in Vostochny on 28 April 2016: 6°C to balmy 17°C https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/UWLW/2016/4/28/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Vostochny&req_state=&req_statename=Russia&reqdb.zip=00000&reqdb.magic=38&reqdb.wmo=WUWLW

Comment: @oefe I've added a few more screen shots to address the temperature. The snow that is on the ground has not seen +6°C recently, everything looks pretty cold and dry, and the jackets and hats suggest not-balmy. There's something in the timing that needs to be figured out.

Comment: "Colder than space": temperature is a property of matter; space has no temperature. Spacecraft thermal management at 1 AU from the sun is more often concerned with getting rid of heat than keeping the craft warm.

Comment: @RussellBorogove ya I know. I'm speaking figuratively and creatively, but I should fix it because not everyone knows that.

Comment: Should have double checked the location- these weather data re from an airport called Vostochny which is in the Volga area...

Comment: @oefe The tale of two Sydneys https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfZD4.gif from here: http://www.cbc.ca/radio/asithappens/as-it-happens-thursday-edition-1.4047704/a-tale-of-two-sydneys-dutch-teen-tries-to-visit-australia-but-ends-up-in-nova-scotia-1.4047709 See also http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-39459471 and http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p04yqr1l

Comment: https://www.wunderground.com/history/wmo/31445/2016/4/28/WeeklyHistory.html?req_city=Uglegorsk&req_statename=Russia&reqdb.zip=00000&reqdb.magic=51&reqdb.wmo=31445 this time for real. A few cold nights, but balmy during the day

Comment: The rocket on the cold days had gray lower stages, and a gray ring over the orange ring on the upper stage, while the corresponding areas are white on the launch day. This gray doesn't look like covering. Are we looking at two different rockets? But there was only one launch from Vostochny so far.

Comment: The snowy pictures might be from the test phase in March 2016. Highs were below freezing in the first half of March.

Comment: @oefe: it's the same rocket. On launch day, those areas (the LOX tanks) are covered in frost from condensation.

Comment: The covering actually looks rather thin, perhaps it's just scratch protection?

Comment: @Hobbes I get that there is frost where the LOX tank are, but the Kerosene tanks should be warmer, and not causing frost

Comment: @oefe et al. It seems there may be the kernel of an answer in the caption for this image: http://www.esa.int/spaceinimages/Images/2002/10/Proton_rocket_on_the_launch_pad (which resembles this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:On_the_launch_pad.jpg) which I first found here a few minutes ago: https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/01/russia-recalling-dozens-of-rocket-engines-sacks-head-motor-builder/ while reading about this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36771866#36771866

Comment: The gray covering is an obvious temporary wrapping over the payload -- you can see the wrinkles and loose fit toward the bottom where it is covering square sections. It also appears the black is a tape or velcro type material. The airloads during atmospheric flight would shred the covering like a flag in a hurricane. Without knowing more, I would presume it was a temporary cover to prevent icing. Any ice buildup (or protuberances) would dramatically increase the risk of an ice-shedding event.

Comment: The trees makes it pretty obvious: it's winter (no leaves). The good thing with thermal insulation, is that it works both ways !

Comment: I imagine it's keeping it warm to prevent condensation on the payload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Starsem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starsem), the Euro/Russian company that sells commercial Soyuz launches, calls it a "thermal blanket" and states that it "will be removed during final preparations prior to liftoff". [Source](http://www.starsem.com/news/ST26-mission-update-7-2-2-2012.html)

[image]

Since this launch was in February at Baikonur, it's hard to imagine that it would be for *cooling* the payload...

The [Soyuz [booster] User's Manual](http://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Soyuz-Users-Manual-March-2012.pdf) states that the payload airconditioning system used during this portion of launch preparation (the "VSOTR") maintains the temperature

> 10 < T° < 25°C  ±1°C

It may need a little extra insulation in the winter.

Comment: Is it possible to address "Or have I got it wrong, and the payload is pre-cooled cryogenic and the local ambient is actually too hot?" with a half-sentence? That would wrap it up (so to speak). Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't able to find much on it. Will keep an eye out.